# Сравнение IF для русского слова . PHP

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. У меня массив с русскими ключами и значениями.

```
$propertiesAds['аренда'] выводит string(94) "Посуточно"
```

Пишу такое условие

```
if($propertiesAds['аренда']=="Посуточно")
```

а оно не срабатывает. Все пробелы убраны. Подскажите почему ? UTF-8

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/10587f474b5308f4eee887f926d3671fec291440

Comment: ну а где ж копать тогда =(

Comment: тут скорее всего 'Посуточно' через английское o написано :D

Comment: или через английское 'c'

Comment: точно . щас проверю =)

Comment: не, все по-русски

Comment: "Посуточно" - как то мало букв что бы набрать 94 байта ("string(94)"), вы уверены что оно возвращает ровно эти буквы?

Comment: кажется начал понимать в чем причина. Только не пойму, почему стоят длинные пробелы, если я их убираю ..

`string(94) " Посуточно "`

Comment: `trim($propertiesAds['аренда'])=="Посуточно"` ?

Comment: да,` trim` помог. Спасибо . Но я все ровно не понял, почему это сработало , если я значения обрабатывал пробелы через `str_replace `

Comment: @Sarkis Allahverdian длинные пробелы и пробелы - это разные символы. Скорее всего поэтому

Answer (score 1):

В строке содержалось больше символов, чем ожидалось.

Функция `strlen` может указать сколько байт в строке. (так же как и var_dump).

Достаточно было удалить лишние пробельные символы:

`trim($propertiesAds['аренда'])=="Посуточно"`

Answer (score 0):

Используйте бинарно-безопасную ф-ю [strcasecmp](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strcasecmp.php) для сравнения строк.

Comment: ну так себе - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9439aabc4b4fb3c52d83f45c23c2828cbe6ca780